# Configure ehcache with hibernate BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, config, ehcache

I'm new to hibernate and caching. I am trying to add ehcache to a big project at work. I added hibernate-ehcache-3.6.10.Final.jar to my referenced libraries. On my config file, I have the sessionFactory bean like this

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.my.project.data.domainModels.SomeStuff</value>
            <value>com.my.project.data.domainModels.MoreStuff</value>
            .
            .
            .
            <value>com.my.project.data.domainModels.LastThing</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">Y</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

I added the following to the hibernateProperties on the file above

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">config\ehcache.xml</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
```

And I also added a ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="true"
    />
    <cache name="Unit"
        maxElementsInMemory="500"
        eternal="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        overflowToDisk="false"
    />
</ehcache>
```

I haven't touched the code yet, but I'm getting a BeanCreationException

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [dataAccess-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
  at com.my.project.controllers.ApplicationSettingsController.<init>(ApplicationSettingsController.java:39)
  at com.my.project.controllers.ApplicationSettingsController.getInstance(ApplicationSettingsController.java:49)
  at com.my.project.client.application.Application.start(Application.java:26)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge]
  at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:423)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:280)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2831)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2827)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1838)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
  ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409)
  ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
  at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:63)
  ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException cannot be found by PROJECT_1.0.0
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  ... 47 more
An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\Users\jtrinidad\runtime-project.product\.metadata\.log.
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT 2:**

I updated my classpath with newer versions of the jars. My .classpath looks like this now

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
      <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
      <classpathentry excluding="**/.svn/*" kind="src" path="config"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid_1.0.21.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/xelem_3.0.2.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jep-java-3.4.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jtds-1.2.4.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-ehcache-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-pool.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-dbcp.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/spring.jar"/>
      <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
      <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
      <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar"/>
      <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/simmetrics_jar_v1_6_2_d07_02_07.jar"/>
      <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jsci-core.jar"/>
      <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jta-1.1.jar"/>
      <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    </classpath>
```

Here is my spring configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

      <context:property-placeholder location="myproject.properties" />

      <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}"/>
        <!--<property name="username" value="${datasource.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}"/>-->
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1800000"/>  <!-- 30 mins -->
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>   <!-- 30 mins -->
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>   <!-- 30 mins -->
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
      </bean>

      <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
          <list>
            <!-- annotated classes defined here -->
          </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">Y</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration">config/ehcache.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
          </props>
        </property>
        <property name="eventListeners">
          <map>
            <entry key="merge">
              <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
            </entry>
          </map>
          </property>       
      </bean>

        <bean id="HibernateUtil" class="com.company.myproject.data.dao.hibernate.HibernateUtil">
          <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>  
    </beans>
```

This is the .log file

```
    !SESSION 2016-03-02 08:43:56.397 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=unknown
    java.version=1.7.0_80
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product MYPROJECT.product
    Command-line arguments:  -product MYPROJECT.product -data C:\Users\me\workspace2/../runtime-MYPROJECT.product -dev file:C:/Users/me/workspace2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/MYPROJECT.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-03-02 08:43:57.992
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [dataAccess-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
      at com.company.myproject.controllers.ApplicationSettingsController.<init>(ApplicationSettingsController.java:39)
      at com.company.myproject.controllers.ApplicationSettingsController.getInstance(ApplicationSettingsController.java:49)
      at com.company.myproject.client.application.Application.start(Application.java:26)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory]
      at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:423)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:280)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2831)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2827)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1838)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
      ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory cannot be found by MYPROJECT_1.0.0
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
      at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409)
      ... 37 more
```

Comment: Do you have ehcache as a dependency in your pom.xml (or other build file)?

Comment: I went into build.properties, and under Binary Build added hibernate-ehcache-3.6.10.Final.jar, but I still get the same error.

Comment: It's a dependency problem. You need to post your classpath (pom.xml or build.gradle or any another file describing your classpath)

Comment: @ben75 I added my classpath to my question.

Comment: Is it because ehcache is not exported?  When you look at the contents of your war file, is it there?

Comment: I've edited my project so that hibernate-ehcache and ehcache are now exported, but still I get the same error. This is not a web application, so I don't generate a WAR file.

Comment: FYI, I'm using Eclipse. I right-clicked my project  -> Properties ->Java Build Path -> Add JARs... and added hibernate-ehcache and ehcache. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: How are you running the project?  Inside Eclipse or outside?  Clearly the error is indicating that the ehcache.jar is not in your runtime classpath.

Comment: I am running it in Eclipse. If I go to Referenced Libraries, all the jars are there. If I check the Build Path, they are included and are being exported too.
I have ehcache-1.5.0.jar, hibernate-ehcache-3.6.0.CR2.jar, and hibernate3.jar in that order. I tried moving the order but it didn't do anything different.

Comment: I will try to upgrade the jars to newer versions.

Comment: Upgraded hibernate and hibernate-ehcache to 3.6.0.final instead of CR2, but problem persists. I edited my .classpath in the question.

Comment: @dead_jake  I think you are using ehcache 1.5 version which is quite old. Can you try with 2.6 version of ehcache. This most probably should help.

Comment: @dead_jake And replace `<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>` with `<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">    net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
</property>`. Provider class is replaced with Region Factory now in hibernate.

Comment: @dead_jake Small correction. I mean replace `<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>` with `<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"> net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory </prop>`

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Where can I download that jar? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @dead_jake You can download it from following [link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.6.0/ehcache-core-2.6.0.jar)

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Thanks, but I still get the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory cannot be found by MYPROJECT_1.0.0. At this point I think it's Eclipse is having trouble finding the library.

Comment: I have these three libraries: _hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar_, _ehcache-core-2.6.0.jar_, and _hibernate-ehcache-3.6.0.Final.jar_

Comment: @dead_jake can u try or accessing using`net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory` in one your source files and see if eclipse is showing some compilation error.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I was able to import net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory just fine.

Comment: This is just frustrating. I tried switching to OSCache to see if I had any luck with it, but now I get 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.oscache.base.Config cannot be found.


I hate Eclipse, but sadly this application depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

this is my spring-hibernate configuration. I'm using hibernate 4.X so if you can't upgrage, you have to find the right packages for hibernate 3:

```
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hibernateDatasource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="it.eng.comi.spring.dao.hibernate.models" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect 
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                true
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">
                false
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">
                true
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                true
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehCacheCfg.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">25</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As you can see I use **`org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`** as class for the region factory and I define the xml file to use for the ehacache configuration
In my ehCacheCfg.xml I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" name="hibernateCache" >
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/hibCache"/>
    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="1000"
            eternal="true"
            timeToIdleSeconds="0"
            timeToLiveSeconds="0"
            overflowToDisk="false"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="600"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />
    <cache  name="MyEntity"
            maxElementsInMemory="1000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="300"
            timeToLiveSeconds="600"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            />
</ecache>
```

In my entity class i have the following annotation:
**`@Cache(region = "MyEntity", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`**

In my pom I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>${ehcache.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Where versions are:

```
<hibernate.core.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.core.version>
<ehcache.core.version>2.6.10</ehcache.core.version>
```

I hope this can help

Angelo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made a separate spring.xml config file, and added my configuration there. I am not using Maven, so I don't have a pom.xml file. I downloaded hibernate-core, hibernate-ehcache, and ehcache jar files and added them to my classpath, but still get an error when I run:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException cannot be found. This class is indeed included in ehcache-1.5.0.jar

Comment: It seems to me a classloading issue... are you sure you don't have more jars of ehcache? BY generating my artifact using maven i have the following jars in WEB-INF/lib: ehcache-core-2.6.10.jar, hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar, hibernate-ehcache-4.3.7.Final.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar; try to check if you have multiple jars of ehcache under your classpath

Comment: I have the following jars in my lib folder, in my .classpath, and in my build.properties: hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final, hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar, ehcache-2.4.3.jar, and hibernate-ehcache-3.6.10.Final.jar.

Comment: It seems to me all correct; may you post the full stacktrace? Or better the log file? Moreover.. are you sure these jars are under your classpath? In your eclipse configuration do you have any other library dependency? E.g. WebApp lib or other?

Comment: more over may you post your spring configuration? so I may try yor configuration in my project

Comment: I have edited my original question, under EDIT 2. I added my .classpath, spring configuration and .log files. I do have other dependencies, and all work fine. This project has been around for years and I just joined the team recently. It has been using hibernate for ORM, but hasn't implemented caching. That is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: which version of spring are you using? it seems to me an old version... maybe this version of spring can't support hibernate 3 and 4

Comment: This project has a spring.jar. How can I check what version of spring it is?

Comment: If i remember good... spring.jar is relative to the version 2.x; try to open the jar with some archive manager; checke the manifest.mf file; there should be the Implementation-version tag; here you should find the spring version... well hopefully at least :)

Comment: I think it's 2.5.6.SEC01

Comment: wow a very old spring version; maybe you should downgrade your ehcache version and not use 2.x but 1.x

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.